# Magento 404 on Admin Page

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, admin

I am getting a 404 error when trying to go to my admin page was working fine earlier today. Haven't changed anything since I last logged in and the only thing I was doing was assigning products to categories.

http://mytempsite.net/gotie/admin

**WHAT IVE TRIED SO FAR**

Delete the following file:-

app/etc/use_cache.ser <-- **I could not find the file in ftp or ssh**

then tried doing this
 Opened PhpMyAdmin
- Went to my database
- Clicked SQL
- Ran the following SQL Query:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: Cache settings were moved out of the serialized file and into the database as of CE 1.4.

Comment: and that means what to me...?

Comment: "app/etc/use_cache.ser <-- I could not find the file in ftp or ssh" That's why you can't find it.

Comment: This sounds like a typical 404 ACL error, but I dont think thos is one

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt please elaborate

Comment: When you add new ACLs for an admin user and you access the page you get a 404 because the acl is saved in the session and is not updated. So you fail the check for the access and get a 404. you can fix this with logout/login... Then the acl is uü to date and everything works again

Comment: Are you getting the Magento 404 page, or the usual 404 page from the server? If it's the usual 404 page you can try to use `/index.php/admin`. mod_rewrite might be disabled on the server.

Comment: its a magento 404 error.

Comment: Follow this, start to finish, to the letter, http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, are you the only admin user?

Second, In your app/etc/local.xml, look for:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Does it say admin or something else?

Third, go in your core_config_data table and try to locate these variables (lines 226 + 229):

admin/url/custom
admin/url/custom_path

[image: core_config_data]

Do you have any caching enabled, or have any redirects setup? Delete the Cache manually (var/cache/).

I would enable your server logs (a quick look at GoDaddy has this tutorial showing how to do it: [Working with Error Logs](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1197/working-with-error-logs)

Attempt to turn on Magento Logging (it should be on for dev sites). You can do this by going into "core_config_data" and look for a dev/log/active. It should be set to 1 for logging (yours is probably set to 0).

[image: Logging]

I would also go further and turn on Developer Mode (which should also be on for dev sites). You can do this by going to your index.php file and changing this:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to this:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**After talking to the user, it turns out it was a file error. I referred him to setup a Diff of his core files and setup a version control system.**

Comment: only admin user, yes.

second yes it says exactly that. 

Third 
Secure and Unsecure are http://www.mytempsite.net/gotie/
I dont have admin/url at all in the table

Comment: Did you do any kind of server changes recently? 
Are you using any kind of tool to update your products (like Magmi)? 
Do you see anything on your server access/error logs?
Go ahead and remove everything in var/cache/.

Comment: nope system logs isn't turned on.. and no this is a site I am building so everything is entered manually and its hosted on a VPS by GoDaddy, but i haven't touched the server configs.

Edit:  i haven't looked at my actual server logs yet.

Comment: Server Error - [Thu May 09 14:05:48 2013] [error] [client 24.XXX.26.XXX] File does not exist: /home/csavello/public_html/crossdomain.xml

this happens every 13 seconds

Comment: I added on the answer to show you how to enable Magento logging through phpMyAdmin. Do you have your code on version control? I can't tell yet if this is a server issue or not. Although I have heard horror stories about people attempting to get Magento to work on GoDaddy.

Comment: and actually is HostGator my bad and nope not an any type of version control and I have emptied the cache, also did the index.php change what will that do?

Comment: it will show Magento errors on the page in the event this was a coding issue.

Comment: I would try to enable Magento logging next (updated the answer to how to do the via phpmyadmin). I'm starting to run out of ideas of what it could be. If no code/htaccess file or url rewrites were changed, this is turning more into a server issue. Hopefully if you can get the Magento logging enabled, that can pinpoint it.

Comment: exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined index:  search  in /home/csavello/public_html/gotie/app/design/frontend/default/fw-green/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 57' in /home/csavello/public_html/gotie/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8703/discussion-between-nick-darley-and-kab8609)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your apache .htaccess are enabled

refer link when you are using ubuntu 15.x:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache