# Magento admin 404 error

Tags: admin, 404-page

I have problem with entering admin page. Magento shows 404/not found error when I open backend. I have already tried [Magento 404 on Admin Page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/magento-404-on-admin-page). But no result. Help me pls.

Comment: have you tried with index.php in url?

Comment: Yes of course, problem occurred after db backup via admin->system->tools->backups

Comment: 404 in admin means normally, that you don't have the access rights to open a page. Check what page should be opened after login and whether you have the rights in ACL (->session!).

Comment: Thanks @Fabian Blechschmidt, I already solved using this tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724995/magento-404-on-admin-page

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem went away on it's own (stated in the comments.)