# Magento Admin Panel Returns 404 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, error, login, sql

Trying to login magento admin panel and it returns 404 error.

Here's what I did so far.

1. Did a check on /public_html/app/etc/local.xml

   ```
   <admin>
       <routers>
           <adminhtml>
               <args>
                   <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
               </args>
           </adminhtml>
       </routers>
   </admin>
   ```
2. Cleared var/session and var/cache.
3. Access with and without index.php
4. I ran the following SQL code.

   ```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;
   UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name=’Default’;
   UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code=’admin’;
   UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code=’NOT LOGGED IN’;
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
   ```

   SQL returns the following error code.

   > #1054 - Unknown column 'â€™adminâ€™' in 'where clause'
5. Ran with the following SQL Code again due to suspected punctuation marks

   ```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
   UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
   UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
   UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
   ```
6. Results:

   > # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: any kind soul able to shed some light on this?

Comment: custom admin url could also be set in configuration. Please check if http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/magento-404-on-admin-page?rq=1 helps you

Comment: Are you referring to steps 
Third, go in your core_config_data table and try to locate these variables (lines 226 + 229):
admin/url/custom admin/url/custom_path. I am unable to find admin/url/custom_path.

Comment: Yes. If you don't find this value, this is not your issue. Let's look at the problem from a different angle: when did this start to occur? were there any changes?

Comment: I am not good at this, so I tend not to do any changes. The problem occurs this morning when I tried to login.

Comment: I did managed to accces and login to downloader which has the same login credentials to magento admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check your var/ folder permission.

If you found error 404 that mean path is not correct if you have done migration try this path http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin

After login system/web/Use Web Server Rewrites set to NO

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
var folder permission at 700 currently.

I do not really get your remaining answers. There was no migration done, it was a live website.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your SQL syntax:

Instead of

```
’admin’
```

(apostrophes)

it must be

```
'admin'
```

(single quotes)

This is why the error message tells you, MySQL is looking for a **column** with the name `â€™adminâ€™` (`â€™` is the apostrophe in wrong character encoding)

Comment: Hi fschmengler, thanks for the reply. That's weird then, the syntax was copied directly. Nevertheless, I have changed them to:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

It returns:
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Tried to access to admin panel, it does not work.

Comment: apology for the poor formatting.

Comment: You could update your question with that, there you have better formatting options (code block)

Comment: Thanks for advice, updated to the question. Not sure if there's anything else I could try?

Comment: I was able to access  and login to downloader url, which has the same login credentials as magento admin panel.